# ImageMagick - partial gamma correction

Tags: imagemagick

I have a RGB image and I would like to select the first n% of red, green and blue for gamma correction while leaving the other pixels unchanged.

How can I do it in ImageMagick with version 6.7.8-9 on Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the first n%"*? Starting at the top-left? Starting at the brightest? Starting at the darkest? What is the purpose of doing this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest isolating the pixels in question with ImageMagick's [FX](https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php).

As Mark pointed out in the comments, we don't really understand the following requirement.

> select the first n% of red, green and blue

Which could mean anything. I would guess that your targeting low values, or low pixel intensity. I'll show an example for the latter; as to me, this makes more sense for adjusting gamma on images with poor dynamic range.

Given an image with random `n%` values.

```
convert -size 250x250 plasma: plasma.png
```

[image: plasma.png]

Create a image mask by isolating the pixels you want to target, and make them `WHITE`. Use `BLACK` for pixels to ignore.

```
convert plasma.png -fx 'intensity<0.4?1:0' -blur 1x3 mask.png
# Or use threshold, as pointed out in the comments.
convert plasma.png -threshold 40% -negate -blur 1x3 mask.png
```

[image: mask.png]

With the given image, clone it & apply the gamma correction. Use the previously generated mask to set the alpha/transparency, and composite over the original image.

```
convert plasma.png \( \
       +clone -gamma 1.6 \
       -compose copy_opacity mask.png -composite \
     \) \
     -compose ATop -composite  output.png
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Just a minor point about the above. -fx is generally slow. But it should be fine for such a small image. However, rather than that command, one can just use -threshold as `convert plasma.png -threshold 40% -negate -blur 1x3 mask.png`

Comment: Absolutely @fmw42 . Might need  to negate that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `@emcconville`. Right. I also noticed that after posting my comment when I actually tested it. I have added the -negate in my comment before time ran out. But thanks for catching that.

Comment: `@emcconville` I edited your correction. You had a typo of -blue 1x3. So I changed it to -blur 1x3.